# TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Пишу бот-опросник на питоне для ТГ. Данные кладу в объект, который я создал ранее.
Так же я создал бд с помощью SQLighter. В конце опроса закидываю данные в бд, и мне выскакивает ошибка:

**TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression**

Сюда приложу код:
main

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'send')
def send_data_to_base():
if not db.user_exist(storage.user_id) == False:
    db.add_new_user(storage.user_id, storage.gender, storage.age, storage.salary, storage.gov_rate, 
storage.city_condition, storage.level_of_development)
```

db code

```
import sqlite3

class SQLighter:
def __init__(self, database):
    self.connection = sqlite3.connect(database)
    self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

def get_info(self):
    with self.connection:
        return self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `answers`").fetchall()

def user_exist(self, user_id):
    with self.connection:
        result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `answers` WHERE `user_id` = ?", (user_id,)).fetchall()
        return bool(len(result))

def add_new_user(self, user_id, gender, age, salary, gov_rate, city_condition, level_of_development):
    with self.connection:
        return self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `answers` (`user_id`, `gender`, `age`, `salary`, `gov_rate`, `city_condition`, `level_of_development`) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", (user_id, gender, age, salary, gov_rate, city_condition, level_of_development))
```

Объект проверял на пустоту - он не пустой.

Так же, хотел бы узнать такое: бот собирает данные на клиентской стороне или на серверной? Имею введу, что если мой опрос буду проходить два и более людей одновременно, то будет ли работать мой способ сбора данных: данные в объект, а в конце опроса объект в бд?

PS: ботов никогда не писал, пользуюсь aiogram либой.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Как исправить

Указанная ошибка обозначает, что вы берёте синхронную функцию и пытаетесь использовать её как асинхронную, а т.к. функция в вашем случае вернула `None`, получилась ошибка:
`TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression`

Среди тегов у вас указан `aiogram`, у которого хэндлеры должны быть асинхронными.
Добавьте к вашему хэндлеру `async` и проблема должна решиться.

```py
@dp.callback_query_handler(text='send')
async def send_data_to_base(query: CallbackQuery):
    ...
```

### asyncio

При работе с асинхронными приложениями старайтесь все операции, требующие ввода/вывода, оборачивать в `asyncio`. Для большинства библиотек уже есть готовые асинхронные аналоги. Например для `sqlite` есть: [aiosqlite](https://github.com/omnilib/aiosqlite)

### Traceback

Надеюсь, что мой ответ поможет разобраться с использованием асинхронного кода. Но если найти проблему так и не получится - не стесняйтесь прикладывать `traceback` ошибки. Без него диагностировать место возникновения проблемы практически невозможно.